# Trying to save Arduino outputs to csv file but keep getting [Errno 16] Resource busy: '/dev/cu.usbmodem1101'

Tags: python, arduino

I have a thermistor setup on an Arduino Mega board with the following code:

```
int ThermistorPin = 0; //pin number connected to thermistor
int Vo; //stores analog reading from thermistor
float R1 = 10000; //resistance value of the fixed resistor
float logR2, R2, T, Tc, Tf; //variables used for calculations related to thermistor & temperature
float c1 = 1.009249522e-03, c2 = 2.378405444e-04, c3 = 2.019202697e-07; //steinhart-hart coefficients

void setup() //initialize serial communication with a baud rate of 9600

{
Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() //repeated function

{
  unsigned long currentTime = millis(); //time in milliseconds

  // Calculate hours, minutes, and seconds from milliseconds
  unsigned long seconds = currentTime / 1000;
  unsigned long minutes = seconds / 60;
  seconds = seconds % 60;
  minutes = minutes % 60;

  Vo = analogRead(ThermistorPin); //reads analog input from thermistor connected to ThermistorPin
  R2 = R1 * (1023.0 / (float)Vo - 1.0); //calculates resistance of thermistor from analog reading
  logR2 = log(R2); 
  T = (1.0 / (c1 + c2*logR2 + c3*logR2*logR2*logR2)); //steinhart-hart equation
  T = T - 273.15;

  Serial.print(minutes);
  Serial.print(":");
  Serial.print(seconds);
  Serial.print(", ");
  Serial.println(T);

  delay(1000);
}
```

And I'm trying to save the outputs on the Serial Monitor using Python with the following code:

```
import serial
import csv


serial_port = '/dev/cu.usbmodem1101'
baud_rate = 9600

#initialize serial connection
ser = serial.Serial(serial_port, baud_rate)

#empty lists to store data
timestamps = []
temps = []

def read_and_process_data():
    line = ser.readline().decode('utf-8').strip() #read a line & decode & remove white space
    values = line.split(', ') #split line into string using commas as separator
    
    timestamps.append(str(values[0])) #append values to empty list
    temps.append(float(values[1]))
    
    print(f'timestamp: {values[0]}, temp: {values[1]}') 
    
    with open('arduino_data.csv', 'w', newline = '') as csvfile: 
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
        writer.writerow(['timestamp', 'temp'])
        for ts, tp in zip(timestamps, temps):
            writer.writerow([ts, tp])
```

When I run the Python code while the Arduino plugged in & running, it gives the following error:

```
SerialException: [Errno 16] could not open port /dev/cu.usbmodem1101: [Errno 16] Resource busy: '/dev/cu.usbmodem1101'
```

Could anyone give me advice on how to troubleshoot this? Or if there are any other programs that I could use to save the outputs to a csv file? Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to connect to the serial port while you're already connected to the device through the Arduino serial monitor? That's likely the cause. I think you can only have one client attached to the serial port at a time.

Comment: When I disconnect the Arduino, it shows: SerialException: [Errno 2] could not open port /dev/cu.usbmodem1101: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dev/cu.usbmodem1101'

Answer (score 0):

You are using pin 0 for your thermistor, but pins 0 and 1 are used by Arduino for serial communication.

Depending what you connect in those pins, it might affect the serial communication, and even affect your ability to program the Arduino (since Arduino is programmed via serial port)

Better use pins (2-12) (if possible avoid pin 13, since it has a resistor and LED that might also interfere with certain sensors)

Concerning the serial port issue:

Your python code should call `ser.close()` to free the serial port once finished.

Once you have made this two changes (changing pin0 to another pin, and adding ser.close() to the python code) you can try the following:

```
- Upload the Arduino software using the arduino IDE. 
- Close the Arduino IDE (or make sure the serial monitor is closed)
- Disconnect the Arduino USB cable and reconnect it 
   (this makes sure that any previous serial connection is closed). 
- In some rare cases, a connection might get hang in such way that even 
  disconnecting the USB cable won't free it. 
  There are ways of killing those connections but you can wait some time 
  for the OS to kill then or restart the computer.
- Execute your python code.
```